# Trying to make an snipe command but get an error

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js, embed

This is my snipe code that I am using to do a snipe which does not work annoyingly

```js
module.exports = {
    name: 'snipe',
    description: 'Shows the last deleted message',
    async execute(client, message, cmd, args, Discord) {
        try{
        const msg = client.snipes.get(message.channel.id)
const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
.setTitle('Sniped')
.setDescription(msg.content)
.setColor('GREEN')
.setTimestamp()

message.channel.send(embed).catch(err => console.error(err));
        }catch(e){
            console.log(e)
        }


    }
    
}
```

This is my message delete event which doesn't get any error that I know but if you notice anything needed to be in there tell me and I will put it in there.

```js
module.exports = async (Discord, client, message) => {
    try{
        if(message.author.bot) return;
        client.snipes.set(message.channel.id, {
          content: message.content,
          author: message.author.tag,
          member: message.member,
          image: message.attachments.first() ? message.attachments.first().proxyURL : null
        })
}catch(e){
    console.log(e)
}
}
```

This is my error I keep getting.

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'content' of undefined
    at Object.execute (C:\Users\\Desktop\Discordproject\commands\Utilities\snipe.js:10:21)
    at module.exports (C:\Users\\Desktop\Discordproject\events\guild\message.js:13:25)
    at Client.emit (node:events:394:28)
    at MessageCreateAction.handle (C:\Users\\Desktop\Discordproject\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\actions\MessageCreate.js:31:14)
    at Object.module.exports [as MESSAGE_CREATE] (C:\Users\\Desktop\Discordproject\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\handlers\MESSAGE_CREATE.js:4:32)
    at WebSocketManager.handlePacket (C:\Users\\Desktop\Discordproject\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketManager.js:384:31)
    at WebSocketShard.onPacket (C:\Users\\Desktop\Discordproject\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketShard.js:444:22)
    at WebSocketShard.onMessage (C:\Users\\Desktop\Discordproject\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketShard.js:301:10)
    at WebSocket.onMessage (C:\Users\[\Desktop\Discordproject\node_modules\ws\lib\event-target.js:132:16)
    at WebSocket.emit (node:events:394:28)
    at Receiver.receiverOnMessage (C:\Users\Desktop\Discordproject\node_modules\ws\lib\websocket.js:834:20)
    at Receiver.emit (node:events:394:28)
    at Receiver.dataMessage (C:\Users
\Desktop\Discordproject\node_modules\ws\lib\receiver.js:437:14)
    at Receiver.getData (C:\Users
\Desktop\Discordproject\node_modules\ws\lib\receiver.js:367:17)
    at Receiver.startLoop (C:\Users
\Desktop\Discordproject\node_modules\ws\lib\receiver.js:143:22)
    at Receiver._write
 (C:\Users\Desktop\Discordproject\node_modules\ws\lib\receiver.js:78:10)
```

Like I said I don't know what's the problem I have been trying for the past 3 hours and still cannot figure out what the problem is.

Comment: `msg.content`? Did you mean `message.content`?

Comment: No because its a snipe command so you want it to snipe the last message not your message.

Comment: Based off the error message, `msg` is returning undefined. Can you log `msg` to confirm?

Comment: When I console log it I get this https://kierandapro.wtf/images/2y9iur.png

Comment: That's a string, strings would not have a `content` property

Comment: What should I do then?

Comment: Just use `msg`.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood your url as the content and not a link to the actual output. Now that I've seen the output it seems you're getting an empty array

Comment: What should I do about this then?

Comment: You will need to check your Map/Discord Collection of snipes

Comment: Alright then I will check.